# Django flush vs sqlclear & syncdb

Tags: django, reset, flush, django-syncdb, syncdb

Can anyone tell if there is a difference between

```
>manage.py flush  # or reset
```

and

```
>manage.py sqlclear appname | python manage.py dbshell
>manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/

Answer (score 20):

flush will truncate (delete data)

sqlclear will drop (delete table, thus data too)

=> if you have structural modifications in your db, you have to do sqlclear (but better use [south](http://south.aeracode.org/))

Update:

[South](http://south.aeracode.org/) has been deprecated.

From Django 1.7 upwards, migrations are built into the core of Django. If you are running a previous version, you can use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#sqlclear-appname-appname says: "Prints the DROP TABLE SQL statements for the given app name(s).". Seems to me it doesn't actually drop the tables.

Comment: Read "will print statements to drop" then. Refer to the OP question to see how to actually apply the statements.

Answer (score 5):

Official docs for

[flush](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#flush) and 
[sqlclear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#sqlclear-appname-appname)

Flush carries out the SQL Drops on the entire db, sqlflush only prints out the SQL that flush would actual run (again on the entire db). sqlclear prints out SQL Drops for a particular app or apps. Both flush and sqlflush/dbshell/syncdb will install fixtures.

Comment: by running sqlflush, looks like flush would only truncate tables rather than drop them.