# How to insert a column to a table in django

Tags: python, django

I'm new for python,I build a table in models.py like this:

```
class book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name +self.grade + self.nick
```

now ,I want to insert a column to the table book,when I rewrite the code :

```
class book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True)
    nick = models.CharField(max_length = 20)  
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name +self.grade + self.nick
```

but,when I run the command :python manage.py syncdb is OK
but,when I run :

> > > from db.models import book
> > >       book.objects.all()
> > >       here is wrong,

```
OperationalError: no such column: db_book.nick
```

I really don't know how to change it ,by the way ,how to drop the whole table?just like in MySQL?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django flush vs sqlclear & syncdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598024/django-flush-vs-sqlclear-syncdb)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell to your database that your models change everytime you modify them. You should learn how to use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/). South allows to create migrations in Django models, instead of writing `alter table ...` South track the changes for you and apply it to the database. There's a good tutorial here http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html

Anyway, if you are beginning with Django, in Django 1.7 the schema migrations are native to Django, you don´t need third party apps. It might be worth to check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/

Answer (score 0):

If the table doesn't have any important data or if you're just testing, you can just delete the table from the database. Then run `python manage.py syncdb`